# Converting elements within a list of lists into integers & then tuples

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of lists, which contain pairs of strings;

```
my_list = [['4', '5'], ['10', '22'], etc etc]
```

What I need to achieve is a list of tuples, where the elements (e.g. `[(4, 5), (10, 22)...]`) are integers, and currently I'm unsure on the best way to achieve this.

I have browsed other questions but most are related to a list of tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[(int(x), int(y)) for x, y in my_list]
# [(4, 5), (10, 22)]
```

---

Or:

```
[tuple(map(int, x)) for x in my_list]
# [(4, 5), (10, 22)]
```

Comment: Is there much of a difference efficiency wise between the two solutions you have given there?

Comment: @A.Prague I would not think so. Just a guess.

Comment: meter it and see for your self?

Answer (score 2):

Sort of a functional-programming style approach would involve using the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function:

```
>>> my_list = [['4', '5'], ['10', '22']]
>>> list(map(lambda sublist: tuple(map(int, sublist)), my_list))
[(4, 5), (10, 22)]
```

Note that the `list()` call is needed on Python3.x to convert the "map" object to a list.